# list files numbered in a specific range

Tags: bash, range

I have a set of files in a directory numbered as follows:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
...
file30.txt
...
```

Now, I'd like to run a command on a specific range of files, lets say 18
through 31.

So far I have used the following ways,

*three arguments*

```
command file1[8-9].txt file2[0-9].txt file3[0-1].txt
```

Now suppose I want every other number,

*loop*

```
for i in `jot - 18 31 2`; do echo file${i}.txt; done | xargs command
```

*this seems like it's a more reliable loop (spaces work)*

```
for i in `jot - 18 31 2`; do echo "\"file${i}.txt\" "; done | xargs command
```

but it seems like there should be a simpler way to do this.  I am guessing the
best solution is to create a bash function that will return the set of files to
the command line.  Then I could do something like,

```
command `filerange file 18 31`
```

Are there better ways or suggestions on doing this efficiently?

I apologize in advance if I missed this same question answered somewhere else
on the web or on `superuser`.

Comment: I updated my question to include a solution using a `for` loop that allows for spaces in filenames using xargs.  It seems to work if you don't have bash 4.  If you have bash 4, then definitely use brace expansion!  **See the selected answer.**  [Shameless plug to upgrade Snow Leopard bash](http://milkbox.net/brain/brace_completion_snow_leopard_upgrading_bash/)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this:

```
for file in file{18..31}.txt
```

It's known as a "sequence expression" and it's part of Bash's [brace expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) feature. It works in Bash 3 and 4.

The increment feature is new to Bash 4. You probably have Bash 3.x.

In Bash 4, you can do:

```
$ for i in {1..6..2}; do echo $i; done
1
3
5
```

But in Bash 3, you have to do this to get the same results:

```
$ for ((i=1; i<=6; i+=2)); do echo $i; done
```

The same form incrementing by one:

```
$ for ((i=1; i<=6; i++)); do echo $i; done
```

Any of the numbers can be variables or expressions. However, in a sequence expression the numbers have to be constants

Here is an example using that form on your files:

```
for ((i=18; i<=31; i++))
do
    echo "file${i}.txt"
done
```

Another new feature of sequence expressions in Bash 4 is the ability to include leading zeros. This is useful if you want to create (and use) numbered files that can be properly sorted.

In Bash 4:

```
touch file{001..010}.txt
```

would create files named "file001.txt" through "file010.txt". Their names will sort in the expected order. Without the leading zeros, "file10.txt" would sort before "file1.txt".

To work with the files, you can use the same leading zero syntax:

```
for file in file{001..010}.txt; do echo "$file"; done
```

In Bash 3, if you need leading zeros, you need to pad the value yourself:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    printf -v i '%03d' $i 
    echo "file${i}.txt"
done
```

The `printf` statement will prepend the value of i with leading zeros so the width is 3, for example ("4" becomes "004").

**Edit:**

Accommodating spaces in filenames is straightforward:

```
$ touch "space name "{008..018..3}" more spaces"
$ ls -l sp*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2011-01-22 11:48 space name 000008 more spaces
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2011-01-22 11:48 space name 000011 more spaces
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2011-01-22 11:48 space name 000014 more spaces
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2011-01-22 11:48 space name 000017 more spaces
$ for f in "space name "{008..018..3}" more spaces"; do mv "$f" "${f}.txt"; done
$ ls -l sp*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2011-01-22 11:48 space name 000008 more spaces.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2011-01-22 11:48 space name 000011 more spaces.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2011-01-22 11:48 space name 000014 more spaces.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 2011-01-22 11:48 space name 000017 more spaces.txt
```

Comment: Thank You!  I don't know where this has been my whole life.  The one thing that I can't get to work though is that the increment doesn't seem to work in the OSX version of bash.  i.e., I can't get `{1..10..2}` to work in my OSX bash.

Comment: Well, it's cause Snow Leopard (for some reason) is using bash 3.1.  This is a software issue.

Comment: @milkypostman: The increment feature and leading zeros `{01..10}` are new to Bash 4. You probably have Bash 3.x. If you need the increment feature or to use variables for the range boundaries, then use this form: `for ((i=1; i<=10; i+=2}` (or `i++` for incrementing by one). Any of the numbers can be variables or expressions. Then, to use the value inside the `for` loop: `echo "file${i}.txt". In Bash 3, if you need leading zeros, inside the for loop do: `printf -v i '%03d' $i` which will prepend the value of `i` with leading zeros so the width is 3, for example ("4" becomes "004").

Comment: Dennis, is there any way you'd update your solution to include the alternate form.  Being a comment it's kinda obfuscating what I'm probably supposed to get.

Comment: @milkypostman: See my edited answer.

Comment: I would only add one more comment.  The methods you've given above using `echo` will work as long as you don't have spaces in your filename.  At that point they break down.  I've had this issue in the past but I avoid files with spaces at all costs.  Just a word of warning and why the brace expansion is so nice.  Rather than screw with this for loop crap anymore, I went ahead and installed a new version of bash on OSX [here is how you do that if others are curious](http://milkbox.net/brain/brace_completion_snow_leopard_upgrading_bash/)

Comment: @milkypostman: It's really easy to accommodate spaces in the loops as I've shown them. See my additional edit. The key is to quote the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to nest things, for example a folder of log files that have been rotated, where there is one plain file (`.log`), another plain file `.log.1`, and subsequent gzipped files (`.log.n.gz`). This will list the first 20:

```shell
user@host logs$ ls -la access.log{,.1,.{2..20}.gz}
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  4995098 30 Jan 21:18 access.log
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  4337943 30 Jan 21:18 access.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  4360603 20 Jan 21:19 access.log.10.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  3168078 19 Jan 21:19 access.log.11.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  1060425 18 Jan 21:19 access.log.12.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  4368664 17 Jan 21:19 access.log.13.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  3410695 16 Jan 21:19 access.log.14.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  3422692 15 Jan 21:19 access.log.15.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  2505676 14 Jan 21:19 access.log.16.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  1322932 13 Jan 21:19 access.log.17.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  1354940 12 Jan 21:19 access.log.18.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  2532294 11 Jan 21:19 access.log.19.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  1476880 28 Jan 21:19 access.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  3011422 10 Jan 21:19 access.log.20.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  1659280 27 Jan 21:19 access.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  3482272 26 Jan 21:19 access.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  3336843 25 Jan 21:19 access.log.5.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  2952699 24 Jan 21:19 access.log.6.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  1220768 23 Jan 21:19 access.log.7.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  3788769 22 Jan 21:19 access.log.8.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  3706914 21 Jan 21:19 access.log.9.gz
```